# onclick checkbox event

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

All I am trying to do is onclick of checkbox, append its value to the URL  and redirect..How do I do this??

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var url = 'http://mysite.com/results.aspx';   
        $('.LocType').click (function ()
            {
                var thisCheck = $(this);
            if (thischeck.is (':checked'))
             {
            // Do stuff
             window.location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com";  

             }
        });
}); 

<div class="MyOptions"> 
    Hospitals<input class="LocType" type="checkbox" value="Hospital"/> &#160;  
    Offices<input class="LocType" type="checkbox" value="Office"/> &#160;  
    Facilities<input class="LocType" type="checkbox" value="Facility"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make navigation? If so, you might want to rethink it - that's terribly inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

That's really not a good UI design - users do not expect navigation to occur via checkboxes - but here's the code you want:

```
$('.LocType').click (function () {
   if (this.checked) {
       // Do stuff
       window.location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com?paramNameHere=" + this.value;
   }
});
```

You don't need `$(this)` inside the function because `this` is enough to just check the `checked` state and get the `value`.

You didn't say what the resulting URL should look like, so I've just appended the value with a generic `paramNameHere` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

if you set up your function to recive a parameter javascript would give you an event that have the ellement that fire the event, you cuold do archive this whit the next code:

```
$('.LocType').click (function (e) {
   if (this.checked) {
       // Do stuff
       window.location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com" + e.target.value;
      //e.target is the element that fire up the event
   }
});
```